# Need help with f-spy perspective mapping on a drawn image

Tags: fspy

Trying to get the proportions for this so that I can use the shot composition but I don't know if I am doing it right. I sort of see one horizon point from the red townhouses but not sure if it's correct. If anyone could steer me in the right direction or just show me where the lines would go it'd help a ton. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The picture is a drawing, so not always everything is 100% correct and realistic. *(How many legs has this spider mutant alien bug?!)*

**fSpy settings**

I think you have hit the vanishing point quite well. If you ignore the building on the left you can align the blue Z-axis lines along the house on the right and the green Y-axis lines along the roof and the bottom of the car. This will give you a pretty good result.

[image: fspy screenshot 1]

Make sure you have selected the correct axis in the settings **(1)** and the (+/-) settings are correct. Otherwise, everything can be upside-down in Blender.

For this image, it is also helpful to activate the *Rectangle mode* **(2)** so that the guidance lines remain automatically connected.

Enable the *XY grid floor* **(3)** to check the floor and the axes. Since the image is very dark, it helps to deactivate the *Dim image* mode again to see the details better **(4)**.

For the *Focal length* I've chosen the *35 mm film* option which results in about 85 mm **(bottom right)**.

**In Blender**

Imported in Blender, you can add dummy objects to check the perspective, sizes, and camera settings.

[image: Blender screenshot 1]

As expected, the building on the left has a strange perspective and seems to be crooked. Because of the low camera angle and the camera pointing upwards, the house would "tilt" towards the center of the picture. But it goes to the left (*so you can see the monster bug better ;-)*) I've tried to mimic this and correct the perspective of the building by scaling the walls and tapering them towards to the top.

Also, the side walls of the building on the left and the house at the very back of the image are not visible. To get the same visual effect, you need to rotate them a bit.

And the cars seem to be tilted a bit to the right and left. This may be due to the road or the monster spider. *(Who knows?)* Of course, it may also be that the street is curved or goes down a slope and that is not at ground level.

[image: Blender screenshot 2]

The house on the left is only slightly rotated around the Z-axis and completely ground level, but somehow looks a bit quirky from certain angles due to the shape. (The top right viewport has an 80 mm [focal length](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/3dview/sidebar.html?highlight=Focal%20Length), all others have the default of 50 mm.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can count on fSpy to get a proper result from this kind of image, because even if it was a photo the houses are not orthogonal or aligned with each other.

What you should do is recreate some 3D buildings that look close what you see in this picture, that have the about the same proportions, unwrap them and put their UVs over the image (if you plan to use the texture of the image).

You can also recreate the image from the camera point of view, select the camera and in the *Object Data panel > Background Images*, import your image, increase the *Opacity*, it will be displayed as background and you can create your houses, move your camera accordingly, etc...

[image]